# Trouble horizontally aligning images next to each other in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, css-float

I'm trying to align two images next to each other. In IE8+ and FF, they align correctly. In Internet Explorer 7, image #3 gets pushed down, no matter how small I make the left div containing images #1 and #2.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bD87z/4/

```
<div style="width: 490px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; background-color: #000; padding-bottom: 10px;  ">
   <div id="header">
      <div id="imageLeftContainer">
         <div id="image1" style=""></div>
         <div style="margin-top: 7px;">
         <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;"><img src="http://i40.tinypic.com/a40ntg.png" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none;" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;"><img id="image3" src="http://i41.tinypic.com/n5mzxi.png" /></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#header
{
 clear: both;    
}

#imageLeftContainer
{
width: 292px;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
margin-top: 20px;
zoom:1;
*display: inline;
_height: 100%;        
}

#image1
{
width: 292px;
height: 64px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
margin-top: 5px;
background: url(http://i40.tinypic.com/2z8w4uc.png);   
}

#image3
{
float: right;
width: 185px;
height: 108px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
margin-top: 15px;
border: none;   
}
```

Comment: And now tell me who has the mood and patience to follow up your totally messed up code. At first make something readable splitted in html and css out of it and then we can talk.

Comment: These inline-styles are melting my eyes.

Comment: My apologies - I've now updated the jsFiddle @SvenBieder .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put a `float:left` on the `div` containing image1 and image2.  Then put a `float:right` on the `<a>` tag on image3 it works fine

jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/bD87z/3/

Comment: That works, but then they float out of their container, #header, and I lose control over the vertical margins of #header. How do I contain them then?

Comment: don't know what you mean.  On my example everything looks fine unless you are seeing this on a full example.  Otherwise I can't help any further